# Insanity workout -  first day failed diet - should I restart or not?

Tags: diet, workout, workout-routines, high-intensity

Today I am going to start my insanity workout program but I kinda screwed up my diet on the first day, and the workout is the fit test.

Insanity Workout is the famous workout by beachbody.com. It is the hardest workout put on dvd. It is made out of 10 different workouts and a 60 day schedule to follow.

**So should I restart the program or continue?**

Comment: It would probably help if you give us more information - what is the insanity workout program, what is the diet you're supposed to follow and in which way you "screwed it up".

Comment: The famous insanity workout by Beachbody.com -- And i screwed it up by eating a little bit of chips on dinner ( 5 chips or something).

Comment: Can you edit your question to include that information about the insanity work on Beachbody.com? Quote what it is, don't just link to it.

Comment: I meant that you should explain the workout further. What are the 10 different workouts, how often are they performed over the course of 60 days, how intense they are, etc.

Comment: "Hardest workout out on DVD"; oh really? Don't regurgitate their marketing--stick to facts.

Comment: @DaveNewton Try it and you will see

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil I have. Even if I hadn't, that's not the point--you can't state subjective opinions as facts; what's difficult for one person may not be for others, and vice-versa, and there are different aspects to "difficulty". Matt's point was that you need to add actual details, mine is that those details shouldn't just be marketing-speak or personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to continue. If you have a normal life with all sorts of commitments, you your are bound to miss work-outs and not follow all dietary advice during the 60 days that the program prescribes. This shouldn't matter for a robust work-out routine.

Also, given that Beachbody's "go to market" model is based on "multi-level marketing", see [Wikipedia Beachbody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beachbody) and [Wikipedia Multi-level marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_marketing), you should have a critical view of all the material on the net regarding the result after program.

Comment: thank you alot. Also im fasting for the next 15 days. Im muslim and it's the middle of ramadan. The fasting should help me loose weight

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil Not necessarily beneficially, though; your body may decide it's starving and start trying to preserve itself. You'll be eating all your calories in a shorter period of time (sundown/sunrise), become dehydrated during the day, etc. IMO if you're just *starting* Insanity, wait until Eid ul-Fitr and start your strenuous program with a consistently-fueled body.